# Simulation in Catia of different versions

Tags: vb.net, automation, catia

My simulation is run in the dum kinetics module, the code was written in vb automation in 
 Visual studio 2010 environment. My problem is when I ran the simulation in Catia R18, 
 the process was completely smooth and successful, but when I tried to run it 
 in a different version, like R20 or R21, an error occurs.
Through the breakpoint, I found out that the error was caused by the failure of acquiring
 the "Mechanisms" in the product of Catia. Here is the code :

```
theMechanism = product1.GetTechnologialObject("Mechanisms")
```

When the breakpoint executes this sentence, variable theMechanism shows "Nothing".
The only way I know to solve this problem is run the code again in visual studio 2012 environment, then the simulation works in Catia R20 or R21, but after that you can't run the simulation in Catia R18, if you want to revert back to the version
 R18, you have to run the code in visual studio 2010.
Can anyone explain what is the cause of the conflict between versions of Catia and give me a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think You have defined `theMechanism`  as Mechanism Instead try it as variant.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have defined theMechanism  as Mechanism. But how should I try it as variant? Can you give me a more detailed answer? Thank you!

Comment: `Dim themechanism as variant`

Answer (score 0):

```
product1.GetTechnologialObject("Mechanisms")
```

Returns `Mechanisms`, not `Mechanism`.

So:

```
theMechanisms = product1.GetTechnologialObject("Mechanisms")
theMechanism = theMechanisms.Item(1)
```

Also, if you have multiple CATIA versions installed on one PC, check which one is the main one (check RegServer command). Check if Visual Studio versions have references to the same CATIA version or not. In theory, they should, if you didn't change the main CATIA version.

You could also get the mechanism through the following:

```
KinematicsWorkbench kinWork = (KinematicsWorkbench)productDocument1.GetWorkbench("KinematicsWorkbench");
Mechanisms mechanisms = kinWork.Mechanisms;
Mechanism mechanism = mechanisms.Item(1);
```

This is C# code, but the VB.NET code should be nearly identical outside of some slight syntactical differences.

**EDIT:**
If multiple CATIA versions are installed on one machine, the last one which is installed will be a default one. To change a default CATIA version, follow these points (taken from [here](https://www.technia.com/blog/catia-losing-file-association/)):

> 1. Open cmd.exe
> 2. Change Directory in the CMD window by typing “CD /code/bin” (Typically CD C:\Program Files\Dassault
>    Systemes\Bxx\win_b64\code\bin) and then press Enter.
> 3. In the next line type in “CNEXT.exe /regserver” and press Enter.
> 4. This will appear to have done nothing but will display the next line. At this stage restart the machine and then enjoy.

Comment: I have tried workbench method too, the same problem occurred. How to check RegServer command, and if the Visual Studio versions did have the reference to the same CATIA version, how should  I fix that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Liu I edited my answer with information about RegServer. Are you sure the line from your question works?

Can you copy more code regarding mechanism?

I don't know about R18, but in R20+ this line will for sure not work.

Can you run the same code in VS2010 with R18 and in VS2012 with R20 and it works in R18, but not in R20?

I'm not sure if it's possible to check which CATIA version is used in VS, but if you set a desired version with the RegServer command and restart your PC, both VS's should use the same one.

Comment: Thank you for you information with RegServer, I will try it and see if that works. As for the code regarding  mechanism, the code worked fine on both R20 and R18, so there is no error in code.